# F# dictionary initialization like in Python

Tags: python, f#

I'm starting to learn F# and I'm having some hard times trying to figure out simple things. I have a python code that I would like to convert to F#. The problem is the initialization of dictionaries in python that I don't really know how to convert to F#.

```
dicoOfItems = {'aaaaa': {'a': 2.5, 'b': 3.5, 'c': 3.0, 'd': 3.5, 'e': 2.5,'f': 3.0}, 'bbbbb': {'a': 3.0, 'b': 3.5}}
```

then there is a function

```
def sim_distance(prefs,person1,person2):
 si={} // I want the same in F#
  for item in prefs[person1]: 
    if item in prefs[person2]: si[item]=1

 // do stuff
return something
```

this function is called with the following parameters for example

```
sim_distance(dicoOfItems, 'aaaaa', 'bbbbb')
```

My question is how I could do the same in F# for obtaining a new dictionary **si** ?

The Python if .. in .. list syntax I tried to use with f# Seq.exists but then I didn't know how to initialize the new dictionary.

I've played with Seq.choose, Seq.map but with no success.

Comment: Not quite sure what you are trying to do, but you could try using `dict [('a',2.5);('b',3.5) ... ]`

Comment: I'm using dict. What I'm trying to do is the same thing as in python. For loop and comparing the if .. In .. To obtain a new dict 'si'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
let test = dict [for x in [1..10] do
                     if x%2 = 0 then
                         yield x.ToString(),x] //note that this is returning a (string*int)
printfn "%d" test.["5"]
```

As John Palmer noted, the appropriate way to create a dictionary in a single statement in F# is to use the `dict` function which takes a sequence type and converts it to a dictionary.

```
dict;;
val it : (seq<'a * 'b> -> IDictionary<'a,'b>) when 'a : equality = <fun:clo@3>
```

Note that

```
[for x in [1..10] do
     if x%2 = 0 then
         yield x.ToString(),x]
```

creates a list ([] is list notation and lists are sequences), and then that list is the parameter to the function `dict` which converts it to a dictionary.

Your function would then look like this:

```
let sim_distance prefs person1 person2 =
    let si=dict [for item in prefs.[person1] do
                     if prefs.[person2].Contains(item) then 
                         yield item,1]
    something
```

Comment: Based on my initial example. Would it be something like that ? let si = 
            [ for item in prefs.[person1] do
                if Seq.exists (fun elem -> elem = item) prefs.[person2] then
                    yield item, 1 ]

Comment: if you want it to be a dictionary you need to pass that as a parameter to the `dict` function, but yes, that's the right idea.  `item` will become the key and `1` will be the value once it's converted to a dictionary.

Comment: @ThomasJaskula I added a direct translation to my post.

Comment: Note that this version and John's version produce the exact same dictionary.

Comment: Does if item in prefs.[person2] is a valid expression in F# ? John suggested a two nested for loops.

Comment: Ah, whoops.  Depends on what type your `prefs` parameter contains.  Assuming it contains a dictionary you could do `prefs.[person2].Contains(item)`.  See my edit.

Answer (score 3):

So I think you want to use the `System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<_,_>` which is mutable rather than the F# `dict` which is immutable. You would use it as follows:

```
let  sim_distance(prefs:System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary<_,_>,person1,person2) =
  let si= System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<_,_>() 

  for KeyValue(k,v) in prefs.[person1] do 
    for KeyValue(k2,v2) in prefs.[person2] do if k2=k then si.Add(k,1)
```

Comment: It shows me an error at the second line in that case "unexpected keyword 'let' or 'use' in binding. My question is also how to define it in the function not in the binding. In the function the if ... in construct doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @ThomasJaskula - hadn't realised the second line was an `if` I just hacked together contains using a loop.